# Static error while running xsl

Tags: xslt

In an attempt to pass Xpath from java, i have modified my xsl file using saxon:evaluate() method. But i am getting below error,

```
Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: XPath syntax error at char 0 in {}:
        Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
```

**XSLT:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">


<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:param name="xPath1"/>
    <xsl:param name="xPath2"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="saxon:evaluate($xPath1)">
            <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($xPath2)"/>        
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

xPath1=//w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[matches(@w:val,'tablecaption|figcaption')] and w:r[w:rPr/w:rStyle[matches(@w:val,'citation')]]]
xPath2=w:r[w:rPr/w:rStyle[matches(@w:val,'citation')]]
```

Comment: Is this problem for `xPath1` or for `xPath2`?

Comment: If it finds EOF at character zero in the expression, that means the string passed to saxon:evaluate is a zero-length string.

Comment: @MichaelKay - U may not have noticed the values i have passed in xpath1 and xpath2 under my XSLT code. Ur comment shed some light on what was wrong. When i print saxon:evaluate($xpath1), its empty, but, when i print $xpath1 i get the xpath which i have passed. I have been using saxon jar version 9.

Comment: Maybe those xPath1 / xPath2 strings have the wrong encoding - maybe the first "character" is a Byte Order Mark?

Comment: I did see what you claimed the values to be. I'm suggesting you double-check, because the error message suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Yeah, u r correct. how careless of me. I have set the parameter as 'xpath1' and 'xpath2' in java. Please note the lowercase 'p'. Thanks a lot